# Keyboard height changes when press return

Tags: swift, keyboard

I have bottom textfield and when I press there I see keyboard and see how my scroll view scrolls all its content top up to keyboard height. But if I press "return" and then tap on the last textfield again my keyboard appeared on the screen but scroll view doesn't scroll enough this time and bottom text field is left under keyboard.

Here is my code:

```
    func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)            
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    @objc
    func keyboardWasShown(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let info = notification.userInfo,
        let keyboardFrameValue = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

        let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrameValue.cgRectValue
        let keyboardSize = keyboardFrame.size
        print("keyboardSize: \(keyboardSize)")
        let contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)
        print("keyboardSize.height: \(keyboardSize.height)")
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset
    }

    @objc
    func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }
}
```

And here is output:

[image]

Can someone explain why that so?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the auto-layout approach , hook bottom constraint of the scrollView as `IBOutlet` say `scrollBotcon`

```
@objc func keyboardWasShown(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let info = notification.userInfo,
    let keyboardFrameValue = info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
    let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrameValue.cgRectValue
    let keyboardSize = keyboardFrame.size
    self.scrollBotcon.constant = - keyboardSize.height 
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {    
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
 }

@objc func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ notification: NSNotification) {
      self.scrollBotcon.constant = 0
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      }
}
```

Comment: I can react on the keyboard several ways but I'am interested why keyboard height changes?

Comment: don't read this UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey read UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey

Comment: I used wrong key in the info dictionary. Thank you!